# Does WCAG 2.0 Level AA inherit requirements of Level A?

Tags: accessibility, wcag2.0

I'm updating a site to be WCAG 2.0 AA compliant and wanted to know if the requirements are inherited as the levels go up.

**For example:**

- Does Level AA mean you must satisfy Level AA *and* Level A?
- Does Level AAA mean you must satisfy Level AAA *and* Level AA *and* Level
  A?

I'm fairly certain it does, just wanted to be extra clear before I commence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell - yep, it does.  No level cheats or skips available.

### WCAG 2.0

Here's the quote from [current version](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#conformance-reqs):

> Conformance Level: One of the following levels of conformance is met
>   in full.
>
> - **Level A**: For Level A conformance (the minimum level of conformance),    the Web page satisfies all the Level A Success
>     Criteria, or *a conforming alternate version* is provided.
> - **Level AA**: For Level AA conformance, the Web page satisfies all the    Level A and Level AA Success Criteria, or *a Level AA conforming
>
>     alternate version* is provided.
> - **Level AAA**: For Level AAA conformance, the Web page satisfies all the    Level A, Level AA and Level AAA Success Criteria, or *a Level
>     AAA conforming alternate version* is provided.

### WCAG 2.1 - it's new, it's fresh, it's shiny

The problem with WCAG 2.0 is it's almost 10 years old since the **Recommendation** was published.  Technology, including techniques and discoveries, have moved on *a lot* since 2008 so it doesn't capture everything.

One example - mobile devices such as tablets, smartphones, smart glasses, smart watches, smart tables, handheld game devices, video game consoles, and so on have all come about and change how we interact with web content.

Don't forget to include [WCAG 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#new-features-in-wcag-2-1) - the latest WCAG standard - which addresses some of these before WCAG 3.0 is out in some form next year.

### ARIA, ARIA - where art thou ARIA?

Don't forget about [ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/) which is just as important especially for any SPA functionality or if you use frameworks like Angular or React.

Hope this helps.